# "undefined is not a function" in dependency checker

Tags: ember.js, ember-cli, ember-addon

I have a addon which used to work in Ember CLI 0.1.4 but now that I'm using 0.2.0 I think the likely improved `ember-cli-dependency-checker` is not letting my addon do it's magic.

The addon in question can be found here: [ui-bs-popover](https://github.com/lifegadget/ui-bs-popover).

My theory is the problem originates from a missing Bootstrap dependency that is excluded by design. Specifically, this plugin depends on Bootstrap (SASS or regular doesn't matter) but does *not* install it as part of the process. This is by design as it let's the user do this as an independent step (in whatever manner they choose). So while the dummy test app works just fine that is because the Bootstrap references *are* in the addon's Brocfile (just not in the `index.js` so that projects which include it would get same dependency met).

That said, the stacktrace I'm getting isn't very clear (to me anyway):

```
TypeError: undefined is not a function
    at EmberCLIDependencyChecker.readBowerDependencies (/path/to/project/node_modules/ui-bs-popover/node_modules/ember-cli-dependency-checker/lib/dependency-checker.js:77:35)
    at EmberCLIDependencyChecker.checkDependencies (/path/to/project/node_modules/ui-bs-popover/node_modules/ember-cli-dependency-checker/lib/dependency-checker.js:30:24)
    at new EmberCLIDependencyChecker (/path/to/project/node_modules/ui-bs-popover/node_modules/ember-cli-dependency-checker/lib/dependency-checker.js:21:8)
    at /path/to/project/node_modules/ember-cli/lib/models/addons-factory.js:44:19
    at visit (/path/to/project/node_modules/ember-cli/lib/utilities/DAG.js:23:3)
    at DAG.topsort (/path/to/project/node_modules/ember-cli/lib/utilities/DAG.js:82:7)
    at AddonsFactory.initializeAddons (/path/to/project/node_modules/ember-cli/lib/models/addons-factory.js:40:9)
    at Class.Addon.initializeAddons (/path/to/project/node_modules/ember-cli/lib/models/addon.js:189:36)
    at setupRegistryForEachAddon (/path/to/project/node_modules/ember-cli/lib/preprocessors.js:18:10)
    at Object.module.exports.setupRegistry (/path/to/project/node_modules/ember-cli/lib/preprocessors.js:46:3)
```

Comment: Hey ken, after rolling back from ember-cli 0.2.0 to my working version of ember-cli 0.1.2 I stumbled upon the same error. In my case I was trying to run ember-cli 0.1.2 still with the package.json for ember-cli 0.2.0.

Comment: Also had to run `ember init` to verify dependencies were set to the proper versions.

Comment: Were you able to sort this out? I had thought of just upgrading the component to 0.2.0 but a little afraid that'll get me no where.